# How is the trivial solution avoided in the Lagrangian Dual Problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The Lagrangian problem is defined as:

> $L(x, {\lambda_k}) = f_0(x) + \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k f_k(x)$

where $f_k(x) \leq 0, k \in \{1,m\} $ is a constraint (that can be violated?)

and we are trying to minimize $f_0(x)$, the objective function.

In order to find the saddle point, first L is minimized with respect to x, meaning $f_k(x)$ is minimized with respect to x, including the objective function.

If $\lambda_k$ is allowed to be $\geq0$, how is the trivial solution avoided (setting all $\lambda_k=0$) when then maximizing L with respect to lambda, which is independent of x?

Comment: You've misunderstood the Lagrangian dual, which is the nested maximum over $\lambda$ of the minimum over $x$ of $L(x,\lambda)$.  For each value of $\lambda$, you have to minimize over $x$.  In particular, for $\lambda=0$, you end up finding the global minimum of $f_{0}(x)$, which is certainly a lower bound for the constrained minimum of $f_{0}(x)$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I agree that I'm misunderstanding the problem, but I do understand that it's a nested max, which is why I say that '...first L is mimized with respect to x...then [maximized] with respect to lambda...', but maybe I said it sloppily.  Yes, λ=0 gives the global min of f0(x), but how do I avoid this?  If λ=0 for all k=1,...m, then there's no point in having constraints, because I'm not held to the constraint surface, right?  The KKT conditions seem to suggest that my lambda values will be non-zero only for constraints fk(x)=0, which makes sense, but how do I arrive there?

Comment: To continue the previous comment and address the max issue: since $f_k(x) \leq 0$, then it seems maximizing L wrt $\lambda$ would be achieved simply by setting all $\lambda=0$, which is the trivial solution, since $f_0(x) + \sum_m \lambda_k f_k(x) \leq f_0(x)$.

Comment: In the Lagrangian dual the minimization is not over all $x$ that satisfy the constraints but rather over all $x$ in the domain of the problem (which can include vectors $x$ with $f_{i}(x)<0$ for some $i$.)